# adding images to the label suggestion

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

In my project I need to create some play,pause,stop buttons in one composite.
For that I created one composite and added these buttons there. Also I have added the images
for each button. But after drawing, it does not look good. I mean images on the buttons does not look good.Clients are not satisfied. Now is it possible to add Images to Label and give some Toggle button actions to the label? I know I can add images to the label. But when I click the label,it does not give button effect..

Comment: What sort of UI effect are you trying to achieve? What was unsatisfactory about the look of the buttons?

Comment: Button will look like some thing very bigger means it will not look good but if we apply images to the label, it will look good. Like we are adding images to the actions. Anyway I cannot use action to my composite. So I need something like adding images to the actions that look I need. Thats what customers also expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a custom look for your 'buttons' you could use labels with custom images (one for the normal state and one for the "pushed" state. Something like:

```
final Label stop = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
stop.setSize(STOP_IMG.getImageData().width, STOP_IMG.getImageData().height)

stop.setBackgroundImage(STOP_IMG);
stop.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e)
    {
        stop.setBackgroundImage(STOP_IMG);              
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e)
    {
        stop.setBackgroundImage(STOP_DOWN_IMG);
        // DO ACTION
    }           
});
```

For a nice UI you could also add a MouseTrack listener and have different images for the mouse over states.

Disadvantage of this is you are making it less accessible as it will only respond to mouse events. If you go for this approach you should look at creating your own class that extends MouseAdapter, and takes the label, images and action to invoke in a constructor so you don't end up with tonnes of very similar anonymous classes.

Comment: Hi I will check in this way. But still can we achieve the effect of clicking to the label? Anyway I will try.

Comment: Yes, with this technique you get complete control of the look as you are using an image for the whole button. You will need to create two images one for the up state, and one for the down state

Answer (score 0):

I have used toolbars in the past to achieve a nice effect.

This will create a toolbar with an item that behaves like a regular button:

```
//Toolbar button
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(composite,SWT.FLAT);
ToolItem toolItem = new ToolItem(toolBar,SWT.PUSH);
toolItem.setImage(image);
```

This will a toolbar with an item that has toggle behaviour:

```
//Create a toggle effect
ToolBar toggleToolBar = new ToolBar(composite,SWT.FLAT);
ToolItem toggleToolItem = new ToolItem(toggleToolBar,SWT.CHECK);
toggleToolItem.setImage(image);
```

Comment: Toolbar I cannot use as I have to add my buttons or labels to the composite. I dont want to add to the toolbar.

Comment: The snippet I posted adds them to the composite.